# substring with last position in php

Tags: php, string

I want a substring from string in php with starting and last position instead of length.
Since we have function in php substr($str,$start_position,$length);
but I want $last_postion instead of $length because I don't know the length after starting position because it is variable.
e.g $str = october 8, 2012
    $str = February 2, 2012

Comment: if you're working with dates you're going about it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
substr($str,$start_position,$last_postion-$start_position);
```

Comment: @BhuvneshGupta - If you got your answer, please add the green check next to it.

Comment: @tbd Sorry I can not vote up because for that my 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

```
substr($str, $start_position, $last_postion-$start_position)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't know the exact length, you need to use strpos first. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

You use strpos($the_string, $the_string_to_find) to find the character you're looking for, then you use that returned value in $length for substr.

But as @john said, if you are trying to manipulate a date, or get some value from a date string, it would be a hundred times easier to use strtotime("october 8th, 2012"). You can then format that date however you want, or add / substract from it using a second multiplier.